# Split dataframe by groups while keeping certain factor levels in each part

Tags: r, split

I am trying to use `split()` to cut a dataframe into pieces according to a certain column. `split()` function is very nice to get one piece of dataframe for each factor level and then use `lapply()` on the list output.

Problem is, I can't find out how to always keep a certain factor within each group. Please see the example below, it should be clearer.

Here is an example:

```
set.seed(555)
test_df <- data.frame(df_groups = sample(rep(x = c("x", "y", "z"), 10), 10))
split(test_df, test_df$df_groups)
```

The output:

```
> split(test_df, test_df$df_groups)
$x
  df_groups
1         x
4         x
7         x
8         x

$y
   df_groups
2          y
5          y
10         y

$z
  df_groups
3         z
6         z
9         z
```

Ok, now I would like to split the dataframe but always keep "y" level in each group.
The output should look like:

```
> split(test_df, test_df$df_groups)
    $x
      df_groups
    1          x
    4          x
    7          x
    8          x
    2          y
    5          y
    10         y
    
    $y
       df_groups
    2          y
    5          y
    10         y
    
    $z
      df_groups
    3          z
    6          z
    9          z
    2          y
    5          y
    10         y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lapply` you can `rbind` one particular group that you wish to keep.

```
keep_val <- 'y'
keep_group <- subset(test_df, df_groups == keep_val)

lapply(split(test_df, test_df$df_groups), function(x) 
       if(x$df_groups[1] == keep_val) x else rbind(x, keep_group))
```

You can also use `purrr`'s `imap` similarly -

```
purrr::imap(split(test_df, test_df$df_groups), 
             ~if(.y == keep_val) .x else rbind(.x, keep_group))

#$x
#   df_groups
#1          x
#4          x
#7          x
#8          x
#2          y
#5          y
#10         y

#$y
#   df_groups
#2          y
#5          y
#10         y

#$z
#   df_groups
#3          z
#6          z
#9          z
#2          y
#5          y
#10         y
```

Comment: Just perfect, many thanks, as always your answers are very nice, I really like the 1st one. Y tried things with creating new group columns but was not able to acheive such efficient code and results! If you do not mind, why is there `x` between `if()` and `else`?

Comment: For `y` group we want to return the same value without rbinding the `keep_group` to it. Hence, we return only `x` for it.